# Best regex string to grab links from many different structures of html page

Tags: regex, vb.net

I am parsing links from many different structures of HTML data, and my current regex string have so far worked for most of them. However, I've come across a domain with link structures like this, and I would like to be able to grab them too..

```
<a
                                    href="http://www.domain.dk/eportal/kontakt.asp"><font face="Verdana" size="2"></font></a>
```

My regex string:

`<[aA].*?[hrefHREF]=["']?([^'">\ ]*)["']?[^>]*>([\s\S]*?)<\/[aA]>`

I'm pretty sure the problem is just that it has other html tags inside the a href. But I tried adding

```
.*?
```

inside the anchor text, but that didn't work, maybe I did it wrong?

Comment: FYI `[hrefHREF]` will only match **one** of the characters `h, r, e, f, H, R, E` or `F`.

Answer (score 0):

This works for the sample you provided

```
/<a.*?href=["']?([^'">\ ]*)["']?[^>]*>.*<\/a>/is
```

https://regex101.com/r/yrdKi9/1